# LINQ - How paginate with single linq query in LINQ/C#

Tags: c#, linq, pagination, frameworks, entity

I need to paginate with a single query, actually my code is.

```
public object Paginate(int Page) // Page = 1
 {
     object result = new object();

     const int paginateResults = 10; //showed rows

     int TotalItems = (from x in Members select new { x.ID }).Count(); // = 100
     //this last line is for show: total items 100

     int itemsStart = (Page-1) * paginateResults; // = 1
     int itemsEnd = Page * paginateResults;// = 10
     //this last 2 lines is for show: showing results from 1 - 10

     int PaginatePages = TotalItems / paginateResults; //10 pages [1][2][3]...[9] (for the buttons)       

     List<EOMEMBER> currentPageItems = (from x in Members select x)
         .Skip(itemsStart).Take(paginateResults).ToList(); // results from 1 - 10       



     return result;
 }
```

Actually i call five times to database , how can i do this with one or two queries (Preferably a single query) and Make this method work with any object (Dynamic)

Comment: Five times? I see only two database queries in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a new extension for IEnumerable or IQueryable. See details in [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/bb383977(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation. For example;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo.Extensions
{
    public static class IEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Page<T>(this IEnumerable<T> queryable, int page, int pageSize)
        {
            return queryable.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Demo.Extensions;

namespace Demo
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Page(2, 10);
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```